# Objective-C NSMethodSignature issue!

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sdk, nstimer

Basically I'm using "instanceMethodSignatureForSelector" as part of the construction of an NSTimer. My problem is that the below NSMethodSignature is always set to "Nil".

```
NSMethodSignature *signature = [[self class] instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:@selector(gravityMeth:sprite:)];
```

The selector that it's looking at is the below.

```
-(void) gravityMeth:(CCSprite*)sprite:(b2Body*)body
```

Does anyone have any help because I honestly can't see the problem at all!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

```
-(void) gravityMeth:(CCSprite*)sprite:(b2Body*)body
```

That selector is `gravityMeth::`, not `gravityMeth:sprite:`.

Try:

```
 -(void) gravityMeth:(CCSprite*)sprite body:(b2Body*)body
```

Which would yield a selector of `gravityMeth:body:` (which would be somewhat more descriptive -- better still would be something like `applyGravitySprite:withBody:`).

Comment: ... but gravity meth is so trippy!